# minimal example of using cloud functions to resize an image using node's sharp library

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I need a minimal example of using google cloud functions to resize an image once uploaded to cloud storage.

I have done some research on node libraries and sharp seems to be the fastest.

thank you.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: That said: Firebase uses imagemagick in one of its Cloud Functions samples, so that seems like a good first candidate. See https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails